# Batch File - Copying the two newest files from one folder to another

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am very new to writing batch files and I cannot get the two newest files from one folder to copy into another folder.  I have new folders automatically created everyday and I want to have them automatically move to the opposite place rather than having to move them manually everyday.
I was able to get the newest folder to move over but whenever I tried anything to get the second I had no luck.  Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You can create a symbolic link to connect those directories so that they automatically saved in your preferred folder.

Comment: Or can you have them automatically created in the correct location using whatever function is creating them?

Answer (score 1):

- Sort files backwards with `Dir /B /O-D /A-D`
- Number the files with `findstr /n`
- If number less or equal `Xnewest` - move

---

```
@Echo off
Set "Xnewest=2"
For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'Dir /B /A-D /O-D ^| Findstr /N "^"'
) Do If %%A Leq %Xnewest% echo Move "%%B" "X:\Path\to\dest\"
```

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in the last line.

Sample output:

```
> dir /A-D/O-D
 Directory of A:\
07/21/2017  23:19               315 SU_1232190.cmd
07/21/2017  14:58               778 SO_45225802.cmd
07/19/2017  10:51               158 PassMinMax.cmd
07/19/2017  00:50                37 WhoStartedMe.cmd
07/18/2017  01:32             1.222 SO_45137227.cmd
               5 File(s)          2.510 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   1.049.776.128 bytes free
> SU_1232190.cmd
Move "SU_1232190.cmd" "X:\Past\to\dest\"
Move "SO_45225802.cmd" "X:\Past\to\dest\"
```